# Cant find simple error in Delphi Insertion Sort algorithm

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, insertion-sort

I am using insertion sort to sort a stringlist (EmailingListArray below). 
`EmailingListArray[1]` is an array that contains names.
`EmailingListArray[2]` contains corresponding emails.
I am sorting `EmailingListArray[1]` and when something changes within it, it also changes the second array, so they are sorted together.
An awkward way of doing things, I know, but it's for coursework and I wanted to put an insertion sort in somewhere to try get an extra mark :L

Here's my code

```
//quick check to make sure array contains correct values
for first := 0 to EmailingListArray[1].Count do
   ShowMessage(EmailingListArray[1][first]);

//then sort
First := 0;
Last := EmailingListArray[1].Count;
for CurrentPointer := First +1 to Last-1 do
begin
  CurrentValue := EmailingListArray[1][CurrentPointer];
  CurrentValue2 := EmailingListArray[2][CurrentPointer];
  Pointer := CurrentPointer + 1;
  while ((EmailingListArray[1][Pointer] > CurrentValue) AND (Pointer > 0)) do
    begin
      EmailingListArray[1][Pointer+1] := EmailingListArray[1][Pointer];
      EmailingListArray[2][Pointer+1] := EmailingListArray[2][Pointer];
      pointer := Pointer -1;
    end;
  EmailingListArray[1][Pointer + 1] := CurrentValue;
  EmailingListArray[2][Pointer + 1] := CurrentValue;
end;

  //show message at the end for a check
  ShowMessage('hello?');
```

The message "hello?" isn't being displayed for some reason :S.
The program isn't crashing or anything so it really should atleast display "hello?" at the end.
It isn't sorting my arrays either.
Neither am I sure if the algorithm is written correctly, I got it out of our textbook.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a good mark:

1. Avoid giving misleading names for your variables:

   - `CurrentPointer` should be called `CurrentIndex` or `CurrentPosition` as it is an index and not a Pointer
   - `Pointer` is to be avoided (reserved for **Pointer** type) and more so because it is not a Pointer; should be `WorkIndex` or `WorkPosition`
2. Read the Insertion sort algorithm ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) has a simple pseudocode for array indexed from 0) and implement it properly:

   `WorkIndex := CurrentIndex - 1;   // - not + in your "Pointer := CurrentPointer + 1;"`
3. Get your Index range `from 0 to Count-1` for a `TStrings`.
4. Don't mix up the 2 arrays:
   `EmailingListArray[2][WorkIndex + 1] := CurrentValue2; // not CurrentValue`

**Update:** Missed the bad while condition for zero based array.

2bis. While condition should be with >=0, not >0

```
while ((EmailingListArray[1][WorkIndex] > CurrentValue) AND (WorkIndex >= 0)) do
```

Comment: Thanks, its sorting well now, just one problem, its not sorting the very first item. Think thats what you meant by point 3 but not sure what to do :S